# Ctrl+C not working with gradle in Git Bash 2.20.1

Tags: bash, terminal, git-bash, windows-explorer, ctrl

Back in Windows 7, Ctrl+C worked fine for killing tasks such as gradle. On Windows 10, it does not. I upgraded to Git Bash 2.20.1, where it claims it is fixed (can't find a web link, the release notes are part of the instal package and viewed locally).

> Ctrl+C is now handled in Git Bash in a sophisticated way: it emulates the way Ctrl+C is handled in Git CMD, but in a fine-grained way.

Ctrl+C still doesn't work for me. I launch git bash by right clicking a folder in Explorer, and choosing "Git Bash Here"

Ctrl+C seems to work when i'm on the bash terminal idle (without a task running), but gradle for example is unresponsive to Ctrl+C.

Comment: Check that Explorer is calling the newer version and is not still linked to the previous one.

Comment: It's calling `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`, dated 12/15/2018. I only have one version installed. When I ran the installer, it looked like it just upgraded the git-bash I previously had installed.

Comment: Could it be possible that gradle is ignoring Ctrl+C? I don't know the details for Windows, but I know on Linux, a program can provide its own `SIGINT` handler, and can choose not to terminate if they receive a `SIGINT`. For example, if you start a python interactive session, a Ctrl+C will not kill the process (at least on Linux).

Answer (score -2):

Try using just the exit command.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When gradle is running and not responding to Ctrl-C, there is no prompt available in which to type the exit command.